# Trouble accessing a specific property in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitmex

The module: https://github.com/yanagisawa-kentaro-777/pybitmex/blob/master/pybitmex/bitmex.py

I'm using `ws_open_order_objects_of_account()` and with it, I can access:

```
open_orders = bitmex.ws_open_order_objects_of_account()
for open_bid in open_orders.bids:
    print(open_bid.price)
```

but I want `open_bid.orderID` and I've tried `open_bid['orderID']` which is not subscriptable. Am I reading the function that it's only returning price?

Comment: I see that I can easily use `ws_raw_open_orders_of_account()` instead but answer if it titillates with pleasures.

Comment: That function returns a list, not an object. Just loop over `open_orders`.

Comment: Can you try what you tried before but with `for open_bid in open_orders.to_list():`?

Answer (score 3):

When you run into a situation like this I recommend you use Python introspection tools such as `dir(open_bid)` and `type(open_bid)` to find out what you're looking at!

Based on a quick read of the source code I suspect you're looking at an instance of

```py
class OpenOrder:

    def __init__(self, order_id, client_order_id, side, quantity, price, timestamp):
        self.order_id = order_id
        self.client_order_id = client_order_id
        self.side = side
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __str__(self):
        return "Side: {}; Quantity: {:d}; Price: {:.1f}; OrderID: {}; ClOrdID: {}; Timestamp: {}; ".format(
            self.side, self.quantity, self.price, self.order_id, self.client_order_id,
            self.timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        )
```

so you'll probably want `open_bid.order_id`

https://github.com/yanagisawa-kentaro-777/pybitmex/blob/08e6c4e7ae7bbadd5208ec01fd8d361c3a0ce992/pybitmex/models.py#L33

For more info on ways to introspect what is happening in Python:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#locals
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#globals
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#vars
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Comment: I wish there was a var_dump()

Comment: well, you can try `locals()` and `globals()` to show all locally defined variables and globally defined variables

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation string of the function:

```
        """
        [{'orderID': '57180f5f-d16a-62d6-ff8d-d1430637a8d9',
        'clOrdID': '', 'clOrdLinkID': '',
        'account': XXXXX, 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Sell',
        'simpleOrderQty': None,
        'orderQty': 30, 'price': 3968,
        'displayQty': None, 'stopPx': None, 'pegOffsetValue': None,
        'pegPriceType': '', 'currency': 'USD', 'settlCurrency': 'XBt',
        'ordType': 'Limit', 'timeInForce': 'GoodTillCancel',
        'execInst': 'ParticipateDoNotInitiate', 'contingencyType': '',
        'exDestination': 'XBME', 'ordStatus': 'New', 'triggered': '',
        'workingIndicator': True, 'ordRejReason': '', 'simpleLeavesQty': None,
        'leavesQty': 30, 'simpleCumQty': None, 'cumQty': 0, 'avgPx': None,
        'multiLegReportingType': 'SingleSecurity', 'text': 'Submission from www.bitmex.com',
        'transactTime': '2019-03-25T07:10:34.290Z', 'timestamp': '2019-03-25T07:10:34.290Z'}]
        """
```

This indicates that it returns a list of dictionaries, not an object. There's no `bids` property that you need to access.

```
open_orders = bitmex.ws_open_order_objects_of_account()
for order in open_orders:
    print(order['price'])
```